# HOw much time this java project can take to complete

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

i have just joined the JAVA course and teach the following in about six months

I am thinking of project of full fledge shopping cart website in j2ee.
so i want to know that roughly if i start that as the project how much time it take to complete that so that i can chagne that to basic project if that is not going to finish soon

Basically i want that project where i can apply all the main enterprise level technologies like hibernate etc so that i can build that in the presence of a teacher
thanks

```
Introduction

    * Introduction to JAVA Technology.
    * Difference between C, C++ & JAVA Technology.
    * Control Statements & Arrays.
    * Methods & Classes.

Classes & Objects

    * Constructor & Destructor
    * Encapsulation & Abstraction
    * Inheritance.
    * Polymorphism.
    * Packages.
    * Interfaces.

Multithreading & Exceptions

    * Exception Handling.
    * Multithreaded Programming.
    * Coding Conventions.
    * Collection Framework.
    * Introduction to Java API.
    * String & String Buffer Class.

Applets & AWT

    * Wrapper Class.
    * I/O Basics.
    * Applets.
    * Introduction to Abstract Window Tool Kit (AWT).
    * Project Work Start.

Swings

    * Introduction to Swings.
    * Difference between Swings & AWT.

Databases

    * Introduction to SQL.
    * Introduction to JAVA Database Connectivity (JDBC).
    * Project Work Continues…

MVC

    * Introduction to MVC Architecture
    * Project Work

Topic Covered under Advance Java

Core java

Swings components

    * Menus
    * Menubars
    * Tabbed pane
    * Dailog boxes
    * Tables
    * Progress bar
    * Slider
    * Swing container

JDBC

    * RDBMS concept
    * My SQL
    * JDBC/ODBC Bridge
    * Database connectivity  using DSN

Java Servlet

    * Server side technologies
    * Servlet Life cycle
    * Generic and Http servlet
    * Using JDBC in servlet

J2EE

    * JSP life cycle
    * JSP architecture(Directives,Declaration,Scriptlets,Expression)
    * Developing dynamic webpages
    * Using html with JSP pages
    * Mixing scriptlets and html

Hibernate

    * Working on Hibernate
    * Advantages & Disadvantages of Hibernate
    * Use of Hibernate in a Project

Java Beans

    * Advantages Of Java Beans
    * Java Beans API

Struts (J2EE)

    * Struts Architecture
    * Struts Components
    * Internationalization
    * Validator Framework
    * Error Handling
    * Database Connectivity

EJB(Enterprises Java Beans)

    * EJB Architecture
    * Messaging in EJB

IDE (Integrated Development Environment)

    * Edit Plus
    * Text Pad
    * Eclipse
    * Java Beans

MVC Architecture

Client & Web Tier Architecture

Deployment Of JSP Application

Design

    * HTML
    * CSS
    * XML
    * XHTML
    * AJAX

JSP

    * Transactions Using JSP
    * Cookies & Session Management

Project Work Using JSP

Testing & Documentation.
```

Comment: Could you please clarify if you are currently enrolled in a course or not?

Comment: any teacher who calls "swing" "swings" surely isn't going to teach "swing" very well. however swing isn't required for online shopping cart apps.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking for punishment here. I am not sure from your question if you are already familiar with Java or not, but if you are just starting out, I wouldn't even plan on getting to 3/4 of what is in your list.

Web Java is a different beast than Java. You are going to spend a large amount of time getting things configured properly and running, even using advanced frameworks to do web development takes a good deal of time to setup properly (god forbid you have a tomcat misconfiguration somewhere).

I would also just drop the desktop application stuff (AWT/Swing). Unless you really have a need, don't bother. Focus on the web.

I would also recommend perhaps avoiding some of the frameworks until you understand the servlet lifecycle a bit. Same with the data access. I would never suggest anyone do this in a production environment, but try writing a small application that hits a database using standard J2EE jsp/servlet/jdbc technology.

After that, start incorporating a few of the frameworks in there. This will help you out when the framework doesn't work as expected and will also introduce you to the foundational technologies that all of the other libraries are built on.

Comment: Can u please recommend me the steps through which i should proceed to learn. My main aim is to build the ecommerce websites using java. If i can do that without JEE thats good then i won't go for it. but building websites in java is my motto

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the http://java.sun.com/developer/releases/petstore/ example program.  Give this is already written, I would allow a week to get it running and have a good idea what it does.  You can spend as much as you want 1 day to 180 days changing it, or re-writing it.

I would also suggest you look for other sample programs which do things you might be interested in.  You can learn a lot figuring things out for yourself, but it can be much faster if you have a working example to refer to.

Comment: Last time i checked the pet store program is updated to follow best practices (to an extent) in java web programming so I would also recommend this. That is if you already have previous programming experience. If not better start from scratch and learn the language first.